# protect the js file download (Hack)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I learning php and jquery.
I 'am using ajax very well.

But what happend if something know the name of mi js file?
for example ajax_security.js, and the he can download the 
file. He can seen my pass key or how the page work.

fos Example :ajax_security.js

$.ajax bla bla
data{can_pass:yess;}

While in other php file are wainting ..
if($_POST[can_pass]=='yess'){ you can enter and do anything!}

Can I hidde the js file from the bad people? 
Is a bad languaje jquery?

Thank You!!

Comment: JS runs in the users browser, so the user can always read the JS code. It doesn't make the language or a lib of the language (Jquery) bad. Technically you should secure applications so you can share / open source the code without jeopardizing security. To solve this problem you should figure out some other way to authorize downloads, as what you have now isn't secure.

Comment: you can disable in that case it won't able to execute in your browser. because browser need to download the js file to execute it. there are server side validations and authorisations available . you can try

Answer (score 4):

The client side JavaScript will always be readable by the visitor, since his/her browser will need to execute the script. The security should be placed in the files executed by the server (the PHP files in this case).